# Chrome developer tools blackbox option isn't there?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I can't find the option to blackbox code anywhere on the chrome developer tools. It also doesn't give me the option when I right-click a file. I am using the latest version.

This link that was posted 3 days ago states the e is simply a "blackbox" tab in settings, but it isn't there for me. https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/step-code

There is also no "Manage framework blackboxing" option in general settings as stated in various guides.

Can anyone help? I can't see any posts online saying it has been removed.

Thanks!

[Screenshot of my settings menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/91jm0.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Black-boxing script option in Chrome Developer tool](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33235824/black-boxing-script-option-in-chrome-developer-tool)

Comment: Simply enable `chrome://flags/#enable-devtools-experiments` flag.

Answer (score 9):

"Blackbox script" was removed from Chrome at some point after Feb 2016. This is a [bug in Chrome. Please star it](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=632513).

As a workaround, you can double-click the offending script, then right click on its source code in the code pane, and choose "Blackbox script" from there.

Comment: Thank you! I've been so tired of trying to find the "Blackbox script" to get away from debugging library code.

Comment: And to keep the public guessing, they plan to remove "blackbox" references altogether. https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1170093&q=blackbox&can=2

Answer (score 7):

As of this post, Chrome has once again refactored this function. It has been renamed to **Framework Ignore List**. [image]

Comment: As confusing as it is, this is what the settings currently look like. Note that the official docs are wrong; they still refer to `Blackbox`. https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/javascript/reference/#blackbox

Answer (score 0):

1. Open chrome settings (or press F1)
2. You will see Blackboxing in the left pane.

[image]

Comment: Update: I tested these regex patterns. They don't work now. So I'm not sure what changed since this post. The debugger steps into `/metro-runtime/**/require.js` even though I specifically blacklisted `node_modules`.

Answer (score 0):

It is currently called "Add script to ignore list":

[image]