# Chrome dev tools, Keep "Step Over Next Function Call" on a single file

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging, google-chrome-devtools

Is there any way to keep the chrome dev tools breakpoints into a single source file?
I keep running into this issue every now and then, where I set up a breakpoint and continue to the next function calls, problem is the javascript is sometimes relying heavily on other libraries so I just keep jumping from file to file, and it takes a long time to get back to the original file that I originally wanted to debug. So the ideal scenario would be clicking on "Next Function Call" but only break if it's in the same source file, and skip all other files.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can blackbox certain scripts from being accessed in the debugger. They will still run, but the debugger won't step into these files.

You can do this by right-clicking on the file, either in the file tree, or the source code area in an open file, and clicking 'Blackbox script'

[image: Blackbox]

**Source:** [Blackbox JavaScript Source Files](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/blackboxing)

You can also blackbox scripts from the **Call Stack** pane on the **Sources** panel.

[image: blackbox from Call Stack pane]

If you have a requirement to skip a certain line or lines in a script, you can use the `Never pause here` option from the context menu.

[image: Never pause here]

**Source:** [Chrome DevTools: Never Pause Here](http://www.mattzeunert.com/2016/03/17/devtools-never-pause-here.html)

Comment: should be simpler than that. now I have to say which files I want to blackbox. If I have 100 then this doesn't work. should be a button just for this file...

Comment: @ClaudiuCreanga of course you have to say which files to blackbox. The other option is simply not to step into them.

Comment: This no longer seems to be an option.

Comment: Use this now: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67449405/23972